# How to count the number of words in the list, provided there is more than one?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example I have a text,

```
text = '''
Wales’ greatest moment. Lille is so close to the Belgian border, this was 
essentially a home game for one of the tournament favourites. Their confident supporters mingled 
with their new Welsh fans on the streets, buying into the carnival spirit - perhaps 
more relaxed than some might have been before a quarter-final because they 
thought this was their time.
In the driving rain, Wales produced the best performance in their history to carry 
the nation into uncharted territory. Nobody could quite believe it.
'''
```

I need to get the number of words in this text, we enter the words with input().
Type will be a list, dict, set this required condition.
It is also not clear how to remove the attention to punctuation marks.
My solution, but perhaps there is a cleaner way.

```
text = list(text.split(' '))
word = input('Enter a word: ')
for i in text:
    if text.count(word) < 2:
        break
    if word in text:
        print(f'{word} - {text.count(word)}')
        break
```

Output:

this - 2

the - 7

The 'moment' occurs only once in the text, we do not deduce it

Comment: Not sure why you need a for-loop here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of this as two steps:

1. Clean the input
2. Find the count

A fast way to clean the input is to strip all the punctuation first using [`translate`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.translate) combined with [`string.punctuation`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.punctuation):

```
import string
clean = text.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)).split()
```

Now you have all the text with no punctuation and can split it into words and count:

```
import string 

clean = text.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)).split()

word = "this"

count = clean.count(word)
if count > 1:
    print(f'{word} - {count}')
# prints: this - 2
```

Since you are using `count` you don't need to loop. Just be careful not to call count multiple times if you don't need to. Each time you do, it needs to look through the whole list. Notice above the code calls it once and saves it so we can use the count in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

You can use collections.Counter() to get a dictionary of the number of occurrences of each element in a list:

```
import collections

text = '''
Wales’ greatest moment. Lille is so close to the Belgian border, this was 
essentially a home game for one of the tournament favourites. Their confident supporters mingled 
with their new Welsh fans on the streets, buying into the carnival spirit - perhaps 
more relaxed than some might have been before a quarter-final because they 
thought this was their time.
In the driving rain, Wales produced the best performance in their history to carry 
the nation into uncharted territory. Nobody could quite believe it.
'''
word = input('Enter a word: ')

# Remove punctuation from text
for char in text:
    if char.lower() not in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ":
        text = text.replace(char, "")

wordcount = collections.Counter(text.split())
print(f"{word} - {wordcount[word]}")
```

Comment: You are ignoring the punctuation. So, for example, you get a count of `0` for `territory`.